# How do I calculate the Credible interval of the effect size? (Bayesian framework)

Tags: bayesian, mixed-model, effect-size, credible-interval

I use R. I have a linear mixed model and I use its output to estimate my posterior distribution (with uninformative priors) using the function `sim`.

I calculate the effect size between different subgroup as differences between the fitted values. Shall I use the same criteria also for the credible intervals (CrI)?

Example:
Subgroup1 has `(-0.11, 0.01, 0.13)` as lower, fit and upper estimates (95% CrI)
Subgroup2 has `(0.09, 0.26, 0.42)` as lower, fit and upper estimates (95% CrI)

The effect size is for me 0.25, what about its CrI? Again just the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than subtracting 0.01 from 0.26, you should be using all of the posterior estimates from which you can obtain the posterior effect size estimate (mean/median) and interval. For instance, generate thousands of estimates for each coefficient, generate a new variable with the difference between the entire posterior distribution of two coefficients, and then use the quantile function to obtain an equal tailed credible interval.